# Call to undefined method assertPageTitleContains() when testing with symfony/panther

Tags: php, symfony-panther

I am developing a website without any framework and I want to integrate some test using panther.

## Infos

### My folder structure

```
myproject/
├── src/
│   ├── myprojectrootfile-1.php
│   ├── ...
├── Test/
│   ├── E2eTest.php
├── vendor/
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
├── phpunit.xml.dist
```

### My composer.json

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "9",
        "symfony/panther": "^0.7.1"
    }
}
```

### My phpunit.xml.dist

```xml
<phpunit>
<extensions>
    <extension class="Symfony\Component\Panther\ServerExtension" />
</extensions>
<php>
    <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="./Tests/App" />
    <server name="PANTHER_WEB_SERVER_DIR" value="./src/" />
</php>
</phpunit>
```

### My E2eTest.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Tests;

use Symfony\Component\Panther\PantherTestCase;

class E2eTest extends PantherTestCase
{
    public function testMyApp(): void
    {
        $client = static::createPantherClient(); // Your app is automatically started using the built-in web server
        $client->request('GET', '/src/index.php');

        // Use any PHPUnit assertion, including the ones provided by Symfony
        $this->assertPageTitleContains('My Title');
        $this->assertSelectorTextContains('#main', 'My body');
    }
}
```

## Problem

When I run `.\vendor\bin\phpunit .\Tests\E2eTest.php` I have an error :

> 1) App\Tests\E2eTest::testMyApp
>    Error: Call to undefined method App\Tests\E2eTest::assertPageTitleContains()

I don't understand why.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me to get the title with a standalone Panther test suite (without symfony).

Packages:

- phpunit (9.5 in my case)
- symfony/panther (1.1 in my case)

Install the packages.

```
composer require phpunit/phpunit symfony/panther
```

Then create your tests.

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

use Symfony\Component\Panther\PantherTestCase;

final class MyTests extends PantherTestCase
{
    // @warning baseUri is already in use by Symfony\Component\Panther\PantherTestCas as a static variable
    private $myBaseUri = 'http://localhost:8000/';

    public function testWebsiteHomePage(): void
    {
        // external_base_uri prevents from exception Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException: The provided cwd "vendor/symfony/panther/src/../../../../public" does not exist.
        $client = static::createPantherClient(['external_base_uri' => $this->myBaseUri]);

        // load home page
        $client->request('GET', $this->myBaseUri);
        $crawler = $client->waitFor('html');

        // test home page title
        $title = $client->getTitle();
        $this->assertStringContainsString('MyAppName', $title);

        // you can also retrieve current url
        $url = $client->getCurrentURL();
        $this->assertEquals($this->myBaseUri, $url);

        // or retrieve current source code
        // but it's better practice to use the crawler to inspect the web page content
        $source = $client->getPageSource();
        $this->assertStringContainsString('html', $source);
    }
}
```

Start a web server with `php -S localhost:8000` then start your tests with `vendor/bin/phpunit tests/MyTests.php`.

If you want to learn more about how to use the `$client` and the `$crawler`, read this:

- [Testing (Symfony Docs)](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html)
- [The DOM Crawler (Symfony Docs)](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/dom_crawler.html)
- [The DomCrawler Component (Symfony Docs)](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html#links)
- [The BrowserKit Component (Symfony Docs)](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/browser_kit.html)
- [panther/Client.php at main · symfony/panther](https://github.com/symfony/panther/blob/main/src/Client.php)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit later but just had the same issue while trying Panther after the recent release of 1.0. I'm using it on an app using Slim + JS SPA frontend.

1. Install `symfony/framework-bundle` as a dev dependency, [needs to be 4.4+](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/testing/functional_tests_assertions.html#assertions-reference).

```sh
composer require --dev symfony/framework-bundle
```

2. Add the following methods to your test case or put them into a base test case class

```php
<?php

namespace Tests;

use Symfony\Component\Panther\PantherTestCase;

abstract class BasePantherTestCase extends PantherTestCase {

  public static function createKernel(array $options = [])
  {
    return null;
  }

  public static function bootKernel(array $options = [])
  {
  }

}
```

3. Set the base uri when creating the Panther client

```php
$client = static::createPantherClient([
  'external_base_uri' => 'http://url-to-your-test-env:port'
]);
```

Hope it helps ;)